# Check if elements in a list<t> exist in the beginning or in the end of another list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have two lists List1 and List2

List1:

```
List<Segment> segments = new();
```

List2:

```
List<Point> points = new();
```

List 1 includes multiple/all elements of list 2(sorted elements), sometimes list1 will not include few elements of list2 either from the beginning or the end of the list1.
For illustration:
[image]
[image]
what is the easiest way to get these multiple first/last non-existing elements of list2.

Comment: So `Segement` is a pair of `Point`s?

Comment: Or how exactly do you define equality between a `Segement` and a `Point`?

Comment: Are the lists sorted?

Comment: So many questions... you need to give more details. Please show us two example lists and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry for the missing details, both lists are sorted, the Segment List includes List of multiple Points, for illustration, if you are driving from location A to B, I have different Segments of the journey, and there will be stopping points in each segment, so in case the selected journey is going out of the area I'm handling, then I need to know what are the stopping  points left(those are not part of the first/last segment). I hope it's clearer now

Comment: It's a little clearer, but actual example data would help a lot more. If you can't edit the question for reputation reasons, I suggest to delete this one and create a new one.

Comment: Also we would probably need the `class` definition of `Segment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly your problem, you need to:

1. Flatten your first list of segments into a list of points. You typically do this with Linq operator `SelectMany`.
2. Intersect your flattened point list with your second list of points and identify those that are not in any segment. You typically do this with Linq operator `Except`.

You'd do this the following way:

```
var pointsInSegments= segments.SelectMany(s => s.Points);
var pointsNotInSegments = points.Except(pointsInSegments);
```

Comment: Yes that's it thanks a lot
 But one more question, How to know if pointsNotInSegment are in the beginning of the points list or in the end?